# SQL Inserir quando Inserido porém ignorar duplicado

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
    USE [RF_World]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.UserStatusUpdater
ON dbo.tbl_base
AFTER INSERT AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Just INSERT everything from the [inserted] pseudotable into
--the target table
INSERT INTO [BILLING].dbo.tbl_UserStatus
(id, Status, DTStartPrem, DTEndPrem, Cash, Bonus)
SELECT Account, '1', '2019-08-01 13:04:12.400','2019-08-01 13:04:12.400', '1','0'
FROM inserted;

END
GO
```

Eu criei esse codigo para adicionar linhas no tbl user Status quando algo for inserido no tbl base em outro DB, porém, isso dá problema porque ele tenta duplicar ai da errado, e o sistema crasha, alguem pode me ajudar a fazer esse codigo ignorar duplicado?

Comment: Não avaliando se um gatilho é a melhor solução para seu problema, o que não parece ser, em um gatilho BEFORE você poderia verificar se já existe na tabela antes de incluir.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode incluir uma clausula `where` validando se já existe, por exemplo com `not exists`:

```
INSERT INTO [BILLING].dbo.tbl_UserStatus
(id, Status, DTStartPrem, DTEndPrem, Cash, Bonus)
SELECT Account, '1', '2019-08-01 13:04:12.400','2019-08-01 13:04:12.400', '1','0'
FROM inserted
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                    FROM [BILLING].dbo.tbl_UserStatus US
                   WHERE US.id = inserted.id
                 )
```

Caso id não seja a *primary key*, pode adicionar outros campos no `where` para garantir que o registro não existe.